# Solving $2\sin(x) + 3\sin(2x) = 0$

Tags: trigonometry

Solve for x:

> $$2\sin(x) + 3\sin(2x) = 0 $$
>
> $$2\sin(x)(1 + 3\cos(x)) = 0$$

Stuck here. The solution mentions some arccos function, but I need a detailed explanation on this one.

Comment: Are the solutions $x=n\pi \text{ or } x=2n\pi \pm \cos^{-1} \dfrac{1}{3}  \forall n \in \mathbb Z$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have that
$$2\sin{(x)}(1+3\cos{(x)})=0$$
then one or both of the factors must be equal to zero, hence either
$$2\sin{(x)}=0$$
$$\sin{(x)}=0$$
$$x=\pi k $$
or
$$1+3\cos{(x)}=0$$
$$\cos{(x)}=-\frac13$$
$$x=\pm\arccos{\left(-\frac13\right)}+2\pi k$$
where $k$ is an arbitrary integer. The function $\arccos{(x)}$ gives the value of $y\in\left[0,\pi\right]$ such that $\cos{(y)}=x$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if the product of two numbers is $0$, at least one of them is $0$.